# Is it possible to remove the arrow but keep the scrollbar in a select menu?

Tags: select, webkit-appearance

I have not been able to find answers for this online as people will either remove everything or nothing.

I want to select a dropdown menu in a way that I do not have an arrow but still keep the scrollbar once you go through the option menu. I have tried to do so with appearance in CSS:

```
   select {
   line-height:1em;
   font-size: 0.75em;;
   color:#fff000;
   height:40px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;

   }
```

However the following results in everything being removed including the scrollbar. Any suggestions?